# android log info is “W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View”,what does it mean?

Tags: android, android-layout

this is the view of this android fragment

[image: this is the view of this android fragment]

and this is the float button part code bellow:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialpad_floating_action_button_container"
    android:background="@drawable/fab_green"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/floating_action_button_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_action_button_height"
    android:layout_above="@id/dialpad_floating_action_button_margin_bottom"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dialpad_floating_action_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/floating_action_button"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description_dial_button"
        android:src="@drawable/fab_ic_call"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

But, the Android studio print the info:

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: FrameLayout, destroying layer...
W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: AppCompatImageButton, destroying layer...
```

and the floatbutton does not show...

I've tried a lot, but still have no idea how it may happens,and how to check the reason. can anyone help me with it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

At last,I solved this problem.
There is a mistake with the layout xml file,this is the wrong file content:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <include layout="@layout/dialpad_view"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:id="@+id/dialpad_floating_action_button_container"/>

        <!-- "Dialpad chooser" UI, shown only when the user brings up the
                 Dialer while a call is already in progress.
                 When this UI is visible, the other Dialer elements
                 (the textfield/button and the dialpad) are hidden. -->

        <ListView android:id="@+id/dialpadChooser"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/background_dialer_light"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        <!-- Margin bottom and alignParentBottom don't work well together, so use a Space instead. -->
        <Space android:id="@+id/dialpad_floating_action_button_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_action_button_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/dialpad_floating_action_button_container"
            android:background="@drawable/fab_green"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/floating_action_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_action_button_height"
            android:layout_above="@id/dialpad_floating_action_button_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/dialpad_floating_action_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/floating_action_button"
                android:contentDescription="@string/description_dial_button"
                android:src="@drawable/fab_ic_call"/>
        </FrameLayout>        

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The "" tag has a id witch is the same as the id of the "" bellow.And I realized that maybe I had copied this id to the wrong place.
So, I just removed this id,and the floatbutton shows  as I expected;

There is the right content bellow:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <include layout="@layout/dialpad_view"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

        <!-- "Dialpad chooser" UI, shown only when the user brings up the
                 Dialer while a call is already in progress.
                 When this UI is visible, the other Dialer elements
                 (the textfield/button and the dialpad) are hidden. -->

        <ListView android:id="@+id/dialpadChooser"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/background_dialer_light"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        <!-- Margin bottom and alignParentBottom don't work well together, so use a Space instead. -->
        <Space android:id="@+id/dialpad_floating_action_button_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_action_button_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/dialpad_floating_action_button_container"
            android:background="@drawable/fab_green"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/floating_action_button_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/floating_action_button_height"
            android:layout_above="@id/dialpad_floating_action_button_margin_bottom"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/dialpad_floating_action_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/floating_action_button"
                android:contentDescription="@string/description_dial_button"
                android:src="@drawable/fab_ic_call"/>
        </FrameLayout>       

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Great find. You could have said that the difference is in line 8 anyway ;)