# Connection to http://127.0.0.1 refused in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I have an error when executing :

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/nevux/inscription.php"); <br\>
```

this is the error :

> System.err: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection
>   to http://127.0.0.1 refused
>                     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:193)
>                     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:169)
>                     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:124)
>                     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:366)
>                     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:560)
>                     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:492)
>                     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:470)
>                     at com.example.spike_x1.meldetect.activities.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:94)
>                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5609)

I tried with 10.0.2.2 and 10.0.3.3 and i got the same error.

I'm using ubuntu 17.10

any help ??

Comment: are you trying to access your localhost? Try getting your IP address from cmd -> ipconfig and making the url like: `HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS/nevux/inscription.php");`

Comment: yes that's what i m trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure you have this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Make sure your phone device and server are in the same network, and change your url like this:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://10.0.3.2:8080/nevux/inscription.php");
```

If you are referring your localhost on your system from genymotion emulator then you have to use `http://10.0.3.2:8080/`. *127.0.0.1* or *localhost* will be the emulators address.

**If the above one doesn't work**, try getting your IP address from `cmd -> ipconfig` and make the url like:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://YOUR_IP_ADDRESS:8888/nevux/inscription.php");
```

**P.S**: If it still didn't work, turn off the firewall and any anti-virus application you have and try again.

Comment: i had permission Internet , i try with my IP Adress but it still not working :(

Comment: How are you using your localhost? xampp? wamp? and is the script working when you try in your browser?

Comment: i used lampp bcz i m on ubuntu

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you please check again? and is the script working when you try in your browser?

Comment: the script is working when i tried in browser with my IP adress and with 127.0.0.1 ,, i m in the same network bcz i m using genymotion emulator

Comment: I updated my answer again. Please try the url exactly as I posted(10.0.3.2), with the port number.

Comment: i tried with 10.0.3.2 using genymotion emulator so the app was crushed with this error in logcat:  09-10 06:57:45.965 360-360/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 360: eglCreateSyncKHR(1285): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
09-10 06:57:46.601 1111-1185/com.android.launcher3 W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...  PS: the firewall is already inactive

Comment: Ah! This means your app is working now. The new error is probably caused by an error in your xml file. When it tries to inflate, something goes wrong. You'll have to post it as another question with your xml file and java code. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40839591/android-log-info-is-w-openglrenderer-incorrectly-called-buildlayer-on-view-wh). It speaks of the same error.

Comment: this is not another error , my app was working successfully on ubuntu 16.04 , but after that i update into ubuntu 17.10 it stoped

Comment: Try printing out the data you get from the URL, if it's getting printed, then it means I am right and this question can be closed. Else, i'm really sorry but I don't think I can be of any help.